# Finding Common Wire on Laars JVT boiler

Tags: thermostat

Replacing mercury thermostat with wifi.  I have just a red and white wire connected to current thermostat and boiler.  There is a green present, but it isn't hooked to anything on boiler.  So I can use the green if I can identify the common on the boiler.   I think I've found the blue common, but would like to confirm.  I believe I just need to connect the green wire to the wifi thermostat and to the bottom post of the first picture,  Green would then be my common.  Am I on the right track?
My thermostat wiring is routed through several pumps, but final connection is here on the boiler.
[image: current thermostat connection to boiler]

Inside, a blue wire is connected to the bottom terminal of above picture (circled in blue on left), but there is also a red wire connected to that post.  Circled on the right side is the blue wire connecting to post numbered 6.
[image: Blue wire on inside connects to a post that appears to be number 6 on the right side-circled]

[image: Wiring diagram Blue wire circled.]

Answer (score 1):

### Tap the bundle of yellow wires connected to the transformer

If you'll look at the wiring diagram for your system, you'll notice that your R terminal is connected via a red wire to the transformer via an inline fuse, and the other secondary terminal has *yellow* wires connected to it, as well as a green ground wire.  Furthermore, there is a crimped splice of several yellow wires hanging below the transformer in your photo -- cutting that splice off, stripping the ends, and splicing a jumper to it using a wirenut (I'd use 14AWG yellow stranded THHN for this, it's cheap and easy enough to get) will let you bring that common wire out via a jumper to where it needs to be.

Comment: Thanks,   I get it.   The red coming out of the transformer is the hot and the yellow is the common.   The sure fire way to get a common is to just connect it to the yellow.  Easiest spot is at the wire nut/crimped splice.    Thanks again.

Comment: @Jim -- we thank people around here by upvoting and/or accepting their answers :)